# isomorphism locus of functors on presentable categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, presentable-categories

Let $C,D$ be two [presentable categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), $F,G : C \to D$ cocontinuous functors and $\eta :F \to G$ be a morphism of functors. Is it always true that the full subcategory

$\{x \in C : F(x) \xrightarrow{\eta(x)} G(x) \text{ is an isomorphism}\}$

of $C$ is presentable? In fact I only want to know if this category is complete (which happens to be the case in many examples; where of course the inclusion to $C$ doesn't have preserve limits). If necessary, you may assume that $F,G$ preserve *finite* limits.

Comment: This seems to be the strict 2-limit known as an "inverter". Exercise 2.m in LPAC says that inverters are accessible, so that's halfway to being presentable!

Comment: Ok but cocomplete+accessible=presentable. So the answer seems to be *Yes*. Anyway it would be great if someone could explain this in an answer more directly (without the whole theory of chapter 2 in LPAC).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you calling them "presentable"? I thought the standard term, even if it's not a great term, is "locally presentable". 

Comment: Because Lurie does so and it doesn't really make sense to think of "globally presented categories", so let's just switch the terminology.

Comment: Yes, the "locally" refers to the fact that it's the objects that are being presented. (Actually, there are perfectly reasonable senses in which we can speak of the categories themselves ("globally") presented, as in a topos of sheaves presented by a site.) 

Comment: Or, of course, a category presented by generators and relations. 

Comment: If your last comment was intended as a honest thankful note, you did not manage to avoid appearing slightly annoyingly sarcastic.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\{x\in C : \eta(x) \textrm{ is an isomorphism}\}$ is cocomplete (indeed closed under colimits in $C$) it remains to show that it is accessible.

First observe that the arrow category $D^{\cdot\to\cdot}$ is again locally presentable. Let $D^{\cdot\to\cdot}_\cong$ be its full replete subcategory determined by all isomorphisms. This subcategory is also locally presentable and closed under colimits in $D^{\cdot\to\cdot}$.

Now consider the functor $H:C\longrightarrow D^{\cdot\to\cdot}$ given by $H(x) = \eta(x)$ on objects and $H(u:c\to c') = (Fu,Gu):\eta(c)\to\eta(c')$ on morphisms. Then $H$ is again a cocontinuous functor between locally presentable categories and $\{x\in C : \eta(x) \textrm{ is an isomorphism}\}$ is exactly the full preimage of $D^{\cdot\to\cdot}_\cong$ under $H$. By Remark 2.50 of LPAC it is therefore also accessible.